# Keras share weights between custom layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working with the keras-capsnet implementation of Capsule Networks, and am trying to apply the same layer to 30 images per sample.

The weights are initialized within the **init** and build arguments for the class, shown below. I have successfully shared the weights between the primary routing layers which just use tf.layers.conv2d, where I can assign them the same name and set reuse = True.

Does anyone know how to initialize weights in a Keras custom layer so that they may be reused? I am much more familiar with the tensorflow API than with the Keras one!

```
def __init__(self, num_capsule, dim_capsule, routings=3,
             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
             **kwargs):
    super(CapsuleLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.num_capsule = num_capsule
    self.dim_capsule = dim_capsule
    self.routings = routings
    self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)

def build(self, input_shape):
    assert len(input_shape) >= 3, "The input Tensor should have shape=[None, input_num_capsule, input_dim_capsule]"
    self.input_num_capsule = input_shape[1]
    self.input_dim_capsule = input_shape[2]

    # Weights are initialized here each time the layer is called
    self.W = self.add_weight(shape=[self.num_capsule, self.input_num_capsule,
                                    self.dim_capsule, self.input_dim_capsule],
                             initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                             name='W')
    self.built = True
```

Comment: How would you do it in tensorflow?

Comment: Well the layer is a Keras custom layer, so I don't know how to do it in tensorflow. I am used to either manually creating a weight matrix and just using it within a layer (not having to use self.add_weight argument), or using the same name scope and passing "reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE" - the Keras docs say nothing about layer sharing in custom layers, unfortunately (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer)

Comment: The documentation says that Keras should share weights by calling the same layer multiple times on different inputs. Like layer = Dense(2), layer1 = layer(input), layer2 = layer(input2). I tried that in this case and it says that the tensor is not callable, since the layer returns the tensor.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to do what you described? This is exactly the way to go in Keras, perhaps there is an issue in the way you set up your layers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple. Set up a layer without calling it on input, and then use that built layer to call the data individually.

Comment: Can you post some example code? I am also interested in this. Thanks.